# Why is the employee saved to filteredEmployees when user input is blank? (JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, local-storage

This is my final project for my javascript class and I have figured out everything but this bug. When I don't enter anything into the user input, the employee will pass the filter eventhough no fields match. The data is stored in an array of objects in local storage as employees, and in this file I compare that data with user input and filter the results into another array called filteredEmployees so I can display the results on another page.

```
// Get the employees array from localStorage
let employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employees')) || [];

// Create an empty array to store the filtered employees
let filteredEmployees = [];

// Wait for the form to be submitted
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Get the input values
  let employeeDepartment = document.getElementById("employeeDepartment").value.toLowerCase();
  let employeeState = document.getElementById("employeeState").value;
  let employeeHireDate = document.getElementById("employeeHireDate").value;
  let employeePosition = document.getElementById("employeePosition").value.toLowerCase();

  // Check if the input values are blank and set them to null if necessary
  if (employeeDepartment === "") {
    employeeDepartment = null;
  }
  if (employeeState === "") {
    employeeState = null;
  }
  if (employeeHireDate === "") {
    employeeHireDate = null;
  }
  if (employeePosition === "") {
    employeePosition = null;
  }

  // Loop through the employees array
  for (let employee of employees) {
    // Check whether the employee matches the input criteria
    if ((!employeeDepartment || employee.department.toLowerCase() === employeeDepartment) &&
        (!employeeState || employee.state === employeeState) &&
        (!employeeHireDate || employee.hireDate === employeeHireDate) &&
        (!employeePosition || employee.currentPosition.toLowerCase() === employeePosition)) {
      // Add the employee to the filteredEmployees array
      filteredEmployees.push(employee);
    }
  }

  // Save the filtered employees array back to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('filteredEmployees', JSON.stringify(filteredEmployees));
});
```

I have tried using the filter() function but it never worked for me, the only configuration of filter that I have gotten to work has been this, but this I can get rid of this bug. I'm pretty sure the problem is in this file, but here is the link to the github for the full project: https://github.com/TypicNine/EmployeeRegistrationSystem-JavaScript-

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Well… `if (!employeeDepartment)` is true when the input is empty. The `||` isn't being evaluated because of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you added some unnecessary codes there. Please try with below code

```
// Get the employees array from localStorage
let employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employees')) || [];

// Create an empty array to store the filtered employees
let filteredEmployees = [];

// Wait for the form to be submitted
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Get the input values
  let employeeDepartment = document.getElementById("employeeDepartment").value.toLowerCase();
  let employeeState = document.getElementById("employeeState").value;
  let employeeHireDate = document.getElementById("employeeHireDate").value;
  let employeePosition = document.getElementById("employeePosition").value.toLowerCase();

  // Loop through the employees array
  for (let employee of employees) {
    // Check whether the employee matches the input criteria
    if ((employee.department.toLowerCase() === employeeDepartment) &&
        (employee.state === employeeState) &&
        (employee.hireDate === employeeHireDate) &&
        (employee.currentPosition.toLowerCase() === employeePosition)) {
      // Add the employee to the filteredEmployees array
      filteredEmployees.push(employee);
    }
  }

  // Save the filtered employees array back to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('filteredEmployees', JSON.stringify(filteredEmployees));
});
```